# Exiting due to fatal error after from openvpn --config command

Tags: fedora, openvpn

I just installed openvpn on my Fedora system and configured it. But my problem is, after entering the openvpn --config command, I get the following error. By the way, the name of the configuration file: client.ovpn

```
Wed Mar 18 01:49:16 2020 OpenVPN 2.4.8 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] 
[EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Nov  1 2019
Wed Mar 18 01:49:16 2020 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Wed Mar 18 01:49:16 2020 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC authentication
Wed Mar 18 01:49:16 2020 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC authentication
Wed Mar 18 01:49:16 2020 failed to find GID for group nogroup
Wed Mar 18 01:49:16 2020 Exiting due to fatal error
```

Contents of the client.ovpn file:

```
client
tls-client
pull
dev tun
proto udp
remote 192.168.1.1 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
key-direction 1
tls-auth ta.key 1
comp-lzo
verb 3
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
auth SHA512
```

I using the Fedora 31. How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the error message:

```
Wed Mar 18 01:49:16 2020 failed to find GID for group nogroup
```

It's telling you that your configuration of a group name `nogroup` is invalid because there is no such group on your system.

Comment: Oh, okay. I can be overlooked because I am a newbie

Comment: I changed "group nogroup" in client.ovpn to "group nobody" and the problem has been fixed. Thank you